# Can't display data in a dropdown with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dropdownbox

I have a dropdown on my page that displays data hardcoded in the class.

I have the following class called state:

```
public class State
{
    public string StateCode {get; set;}
    public string StateName { get; set; }

    public static IQueryable<State> GetStates()
    {
        return new List<State>
        {
            new State{
                StateCode="DE",
                StateName="Delaware"
            },
            new State{
                StateCode="NJ",
                StateName="New Jersey"
            },
            new State{
                StateCode="PA",
                StateName="Pennsylvania"
            }

        }.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

My Home controller has the following actions:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult StateList()
    {
        IQueryable states = State.GetStates();
        if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return Json(new SelectList(states,
                "StateCode",
                "StateCode"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                );
       }
        return View(states);
    }
```

and here is what I have in my view:

```
@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $.getJSON("/Home/States/List", function (data) {
        var items = "<option>Please Select</option>"
        $.each(data, function (i, state) {
            items += "<option value='" + state.Value + "'>" + state.Text + "</option>";
        });
        $("States").html(items);
    });


});

</script>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

<label for="States"></label>
<br />
<select id="States" name="States"></select>

}
```

I also added this to my routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "StatesList",
            "Home/States/List",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "StateList" }
        );
```

I do not get any errors but also no data shows up in my dropdown box. I tried debugging my controller and I can see that the state data gets into the object states inside the action. Can anyone help me diagnose the problem?

Comment: `$("States").html(items);` should be `$("#States").html(items);`. (but you really should read the link I gave you in your now deleted last question)

Comment: @StephenMuecke your comment is an answer and should be posted as such.

Comment: @ChrisPietschmann, On my TODO list :) - want to also address some other issues with OP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("States").html(items);` needs to be `$("#States").html(items);` (the hash indicates a [jQuery ID Selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/))

Side notes:

1. [IQueryable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562(v=vs.100).aspx) GetStates() should really be [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.100).aspx)
   GetStates() (refer linked documentation)
2. There is no need for the extra overhead of creating a `SelectList`
   in the `StateList()` method. It can be simply `return Json(states,
   JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` and then in the ajax `success`
   function: `items += "<option value='" + state.StateCode + "'>" +
   state.StateName + "</option>";`
3. Currently if the first option ("Please Select") is selected, it will
   post back the value `Please Select` which I suspect is not what you
   want. Intead, give the option a `null` value (which you can then use
   in conjunction with a `[Required]` attribute to force a selection).
   For example: `var items = $('<option>Please Select</option>').val('');`